# Gridsizes when drawing a grid on a canvas

Tags: canvas

See the following plunk: [Canvas raster](https://plnkr.co/edit/KdDQKjoh1xilG6H0?preview)

The canvas size is 120px wide by 80px high.
This code draws the vertical lines:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= this.CanvasWidth*2.5; x += gridSize*1.25) {
    ctx.moveTo(x + p, p);
    ctx.lineTo(x + p, this.CanvasHeight*2.5 + p);
}
```

As you notice I had to correct the canvas width and height by factor 2.5, and the grid size by 1.25. p is for padding, and has value 0.
It doesn't make sense to me. As I want grids of 10x10 pixels, I thought an increment of 10 (var gridSize) should do it. Same applies to the canvas width and height, if I use the CanvasWidth and CanvasHeight properties it will only cover part of the canvas.

Can anyone tell me whats is going on? Thx!

Comment: I think that the mix of canvas and CSS is causing that...
try again without any CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Mix of CSS is causing some issues in your code, here is the same grid no CSS

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("grid")
canvas.width = 120;
canvas.height = 80;
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

var gridSize = 20;

for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.width; x += gridSize) {
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
}

for (var y = 0; y <= canvas.height; y += gridSize) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
}

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="grid"></canvas>
```

As you can see I have no CSS and there is no factor added in the for loops.
But it's important to notice that I do set the size of the canvas:

```
canvas.width = 120;
canvas.height = 80;
```

Comment: Thx a lot Helder, setting width and height of the canvas with CSS causes "the strange behavior". I updated my plunk, and now it does what I expected!

Comment: Awesome! ye I try to keep my CSS away from the canvas, they do not mix well